# Read file into bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, file

How can I make this work?

I have test data: test.dat

```
red apples
green tomato
yellow lemon
```

I've tried numerous examples that I could find to no avail.

Obviously there is something about the shell I don't understand...

```
#!/bin/bash

#lines=$(IFS='\n' cat $1)
#IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  
#lines=($(cat test.dat))
#IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < test.dat
#readarray -t lines < test.dat
#lines=$(cat test.dat)

lines=$(< test.dat)


for line in $lines
do
  echo "${line}"
done

printf "line 1: %s\n" "${lines[1]}"
echo "line 2: ${lines[2]}"
```

Output:

```
./test.sh test.dat
red
apples
green
tomato
yellow
lemon
./test.sh line 71: lines[1]: unbound variable
```

Comment: What does it mean for it to work? What do you expect to happen? What is wrong with that `readarray` command you already have the, within the commented part?

Comment: I want to be able to access the data via $line & "${lines[n]}  And as you can see it is splitting the lines.

Comment: That should work if you use `readarray`.

Comment: `for line in "${lines[@]}"` is how you loop over the array.

Comment: `lines=$(< test.dat)` isn't creating an array, it's a single string.

Comment: `set -A myarray $(tr -s '\n' ' ' < infile)`

Comment: Thank you Barmar! That worked. I had tried readarray but not with ${lines[@]} in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using the readarray command should work, `readarray -t a < /path/to/filename`